# Power supply for LED display

Tags: power-supply

I've created a special microcontroller driven LED display which I need power supply for. The display uses 24VDC and draws any current between 0 and 8 amps depending on how many LEDs are illuminated. Most of the time it's not illuminated and only microcontroller needs a little power.

So far I've used a battery charger as power supply for testing but I will need a proper power supply for it. The power supply needs to be weatherproof as it's going to be installed outside.

But it's very hard to find this kind of power supplies. So far I've found some LED power supplies like [Mean Well HLG-240-24](http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=hlg-240h). Can I use this kind of power supply for my project? I think not as it's a constant current supply. Am I right? What other options I have?

Comment: 8A for LEDs ??? Wow.. Offtopic, anyway.

Comment: 8 amps? Almost 200 Watts?

Comment: That's right. There are over one thousand LEDs in the display.

Comment: How about sticking a non-weatherproof power supply in a weatherproof box?  Just ensure it doesn't need ventilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without directing you to a specific supply,  you already know most of what you need to find.

Outdoor rated supply, so you want one with an IP rating of 66, 67 or 68.

Constant Voltage, as you need variable output.

Since you need 24v at 8 Amps (195 Watts), adding in a margin of safety, look for a 210 Watt or higher supply.

If you are willing to add in a switching voltage regulator, you could look for a higher voltage supply and regulate down. 48V 5A for example.